# Facebook App WhiteList process

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, whitelist

Does anyone know a process of getting a FB app whitelisted to enable certain features? I have seen few people asking the same question, but no answers. Is there a contact at FB who deals with whitelist applications?

Answer (score 4):

There is no public process though which to apply for whitelists.

Facebook, like most companies, is likely to have a small number of private APIs which are only available to whitelisted partners - but they're only made available to those close partners.

Facebook has some features which you may request access to as part of their review process: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review. At the time of writing, these only include the Taggable Friends API and Page Mentions.