# how uber app get mobile number from facebook in android

Tags: android

How could uber android application get my mobile number while facebook login

I am using Facebook login in my android app and i want user mobile number from facebook but i am not getting it following is my android code

```
 private void FbInitialise() {

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends"));

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            graphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            graphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });
}

  public void graphRequest(AccessToken token) {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(token, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

            try {
                LoginType="FB";
                String firstName = "";
                String lastName = "";
                String stremail = "";
                String strmobile = "";

                if (object.has("first_name")) {
                    firstName = object.getString("first_name");
                }
                if (object.has("last_name")) {
                    lastName = object.getString("last_name");
                }if (object.has("email")) {
                    stremail = object.getString("email");
                }

                Intent intent=new Intent(SelectSocilaLoginActivity.this,ConfirmInfoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("firstName",firstName);
                intent.putExtra("lastName",lastName);
                intent.putExtra("email",stremail);
                intent.putExtra("parent","SocialLogin");
                startActivity(intent);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email,gender, birthday, location");
    request.setParameters(b);
    request.executeAsync();

}
```

please give me proper solution

Comment: you have to get that approved by facebook first

Comment: how to get approval from facebook

Answer (score -1):

**Here is how I managed to extract mobile number from the Login user's profile:**

```
public class UserAuth extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
private Context context;
private Button btnViewProfile;

//For User data
private String userId, userFirstName, userMiddleName, userLastName, userProfileImage, userEmail, userGender, userMobile, userBirthdate;

//For Facebook
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
LoginButton loginButton = null;
private ImageButton btnFacebook;
private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* Enabling strict mode */
    setStrictThreadMode();

    //initializing facebook sdk
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    //Initialize your view components available in the layout

    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken,
                                                   AccessToken newToken) {
        }
    };

    profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile,
                                               Profile newProfile) {
            if (newProfile != null) {
                userId = newProfile.getId();
                userFirstName = newProfile.getFirstName();
                userMiddleName = newProfile.getMiddleName();
                userLastName = newProfile.getLastName();
                userProfileImage = newProfile.getProfilePictureUri(400, 400).toString();
            }
        }
    };

    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
    profileTracker.startTracking();
}

//To enable single thread at a time mode
private void setStrictThreadMode() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    profileTracker.stopTracking();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
}

//This method initializes the facebook login button, sets the required permissions and changes its default background to our drawable
//It also registers the callback for the Login button
private void registerLoginButton() {
    List<String> mPermissions = new ArrayList<>();
    mPermissions.add("public_profile");
    mPermissions.add("email");
    mPermissions.add("user_birthday");
    mPermissions.add("user_friends");
    mPermissions.add("user_mobile_phone");

    loginButton.setReadPermissions(mPermissions);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(result.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        userEmail = object.optString("email");
                        userGender = object.optString("gender");
                        userMobile = object.optString("mobile_phone");
                        String userBirthdate = object.optString("birthday");
                        logoutCurrentUser();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        }
    });
}

//This method is to end the current users session
private void logoutCurrentUser() {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}
```

}

*Observe we have added permission for fetching mobile number: mPermissions.add("user_mobile_phone");*

Also, please remember that you will only get the mobile number if the user has made it public.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: i tried your method, but still can't get the phone number. I read something about a white list so that facebook would allow you to get the number, do you know something about it?

Comment: @karique I have mentioned very clearly that a number will only be fetched if the respective user has made their mobile number as public and not otherwise. Also please be specific what you have read about white list and what exactly do you need from it? To know more about getting white listed have you read the Facebook community forum?

Comment: @karique You can check this to know what a whitelist means. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994546/facebook-app-whitelist-process

Comment: Yes, my number is already public, but still i'm not getting it, there's no problem with the others fields like email and name. Also i tried with uber and the number it appears when i try the register process by facebook. Apparently there is a group that facebook allows to get the mobile number.